# bind checkbox enable property to code behind method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a check box on  a page. I want to set it's enable property from a codebehind method.
I have done this  `Enabled= '<%#IsSMSEnabled()%>' />`

IsSMSEnabled returns true or false depending on some logic.

Check box is alwyas enabled no matter what is returned by IsSMSEnabled()%

Comment: I would try just added true and false first

Comment: if I set to enabled false at design time then it's disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<%# expressions` are evaluated at `DataBind()` time and are not evaluated at all if `DataBind()` is not called. You can call `DataBind()` in `PreRenderComplete`

```
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you return the value from.

Try to set a property and assign its value inside code behind.

**EDIT**

I just heard that your checkbox is not inside a data control. So that would make more sense to directly change the checkbox.Checked value.

Comment: I read some values in session and depending on that IsSMSEnabled() returns true or false

Comment: my money is on that your databinding is probably happening before your bool method. a good debugging would make it more clear. And one more question : is your checkbox inside a data control, like DataList?

Comment: it's not in any databound controls but on a panel which is invisible on page lod. and on Add new button click this panel become visible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping your method call in `<%# %>`, try wrapping it in `<%= %>`

```
<%= sSMSEnabled() %>
```

Comment: Nope - did not work. Got following error.Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%=IsSMSEnabled()%>' for the 'Enabled' property.

Answer (score 0):

try `<%= bool.Parse(IsSMSEnabled()) %>`